# How to use SUM() and merge tables into one table with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

What I have is **4 separate `SELECT` queries** and they has the same data. Hence, I would like to merge these data into **ONE** temporary table.

How to:

1. Merge 4 tables into one table first
2. then SUM() columns

as my image below. I've tried but it didn't work.

[image: Merge]

**SQL:**

```
DECLARE @Plants TABLE
(
    PlantName nvarchar(30),
    MaterialTotalPrice DECIMAL,
    SumLaborCost DECIMAL,
    FinalCost DECIMAL
)

DECLARE @MaterialTotalPrice DECIMAL
DECLARE @SumLaborCost DECIMAL
DECLARE @FinalCost DECIMAL

SELECT
    @MaterialTotalPrice = SUM(GetTotalPrice.[MaterialTotalPrice])
    ,@SumLaborCost = SUM(GetTotalPrice.[SumLaborCost])
    ,@FinalCost = SUM(GetTotalPrice.[FinalCost])
FROM
(

    SELECT
        TotalPriceMP4.[PlantName]
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[MaterialTotalPrice]) AS 'MaterialTotalPrice'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[SumLaborCost]) AS 'SumLaborCost'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[FinalCost]) AS 'FinalCost'
    FROM Invoice1 AS TotalPriceMP4
    GROUP BY TotalPriceMP4.[PlantName]

    SELECT
        TotalPriceMP4.[PlantName]
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[MaterialTotalPrice]) AS 'MaterialTotalPrice'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[SumLaborCost]) AS 'SumLaborCost'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[FinalCost]) AS 'FinalCost'
    FROM Invoice2 AS TotalPriceMP4
    GROUP BY TotalPriceMP4.[PlantName]

    SELECT
        TotalPriceMP4.[PlantName]
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[MaterialTotalPrice]) AS 'MaterialTotalPrice'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[SumLaborCost]) AS 'SumLaborCost'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[FinalCost]) AS 'FinalCost'
    FROM Invoice3 AS TotalPriceMP4
    GROUP BY TotalPriceMP4.[PlantName]

    SELECT
        TotalPriceMP4.[PlantName]
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[MaterialTotalPrice]) AS 'MaterialTotalPrice'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[SumLaborCost]) AS 'SumLaborCost'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[FinalCost]) AS 'FinalCost'
    FROM Invoice4 AS TotalPriceMP4
    GROUP BY TotalPriceMP4.[PlantName]

) AS GetTotalPrice
INSERT INTO @Plants(PlantName, MaterialTotalPrice, SumLaborCost, FinalCost) VALUES ('P4', ISNULL(@MaterialTotalPrice,0), ISNULL(@SumLaborCost,0), ISNULL(@FinalCost,0))
SELECT * FROM @Plants
```

Comment: UNION the results together

Comment: @DavidG: Could you please give me a full answer?

Comment: ...I'm a bit concerned about the fact that you have tables with an increment number (ie, `Invoice1`, `Invoice2`, etc).  You should combine the tables if possible.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: Your idea is great. However, it was solid and I can't make a change for these...

Comment: You could also create a view to show these 4 tables as one if you regularly need to treat them that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to UNION the results together which merges those (identical) result sets into one.

```
DECLARE @Plants TABLE
(
    PlantName nvarchar(30),
    MaterialTotalPrice DECIMAL,
    SumLaborCost DECIMAL,
    FinalCost DECIMAL
)

DECLARE @MaterialTotalPrice DECIMAL
DECLARE @SumLaborCost DECIMAL
DECLARE @FinalCost DECIMAL

SELECT
    @MaterialTotalPrice = SUM(GetTotalPrice.[MaterialTotalPrice])
    ,@SumLaborCost = SUM(GetTotalPrice.[SumLaborCost])
    ,@FinalCost = SUM(GetTotalPrice.[FinalCost])
FROM
(
    SELECT
        TotalPriceMP4.[PlantName]
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[MaterialTotalPrice]) AS 'MaterialTotalPrice'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[SumLaborCost]) AS 'SumLaborCost'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[FinalCost]) AS 'FinalCost'
    FROM Invoice1 AS TotalPriceMP4
    GROUP BY TotalPriceMP4.[PlantName]
    UNION
    SELECT
        TotalPriceMP4.[PlantName]
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[MaterialTotalPrice]) AS 'MaterialTotalPrice'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[SumLaborCost]) AS 'SumLaborCost'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[FinalCost]) AS 'FinalCost'
    FROM Invoice2 AS TotalPriceMP4
    GROUP BY TotalPriceMP4.[PlantName]
    UNION
    SELECT
        TotalPriceMP4.[PlantName]
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[MaterialTotalPrice]) AS 'MaterialTotalPrice'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[SumLaborCost]) AS 'SumLaborCost'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[FinalCost]) AS 'FinalCost'
    FROM Invoice3 AS TotalPriceMP4
    GROUP BY TotalPriceMP4.[PlantName]
    UNION
    SELECT
        TotalPriceMP4.[PlantName]
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[MaterialTotalPrice]) AS 'MaterialTotalPrice'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[SumLaborCost]) AS 'SumLaborCost'
        ,SUM(TotalPriceMP4.[FinalCost]) AS 'FinalCost'
    FROM Invoice4 AS TotalPriceMP4
    GROUP BY TotalPriceMP4.[PlantName]

) AS GetTotalPrice
INSERT INTO @Plants(PlantName, MaterialTotalPrice, SumLaborCost, FinalCost) VALUES ('P4', ISNULL(@MaterialTotalPrice,0), ISNULL(@SumLaborCost,0), ISNULL(@FinalCost,0))
SELECT * FROM @Plants
```

Comment: It's OK. The system forces me to wait for a period of time in order to send a reputation.